# Puppet: how to add a line to an existing file

Tags: puppet

**Edit:** *The example below is correct and works perfectly. But for some reason it was not working for me at the first time and then I did `vagrant provision` and then everything worked perfectly.*

I am trying to add a line to an existing file /etc/fuse.conf. I tried this

added a folder two folders under modules directory

```
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test
sudo mkdir /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests
```

Then created a test.pp file and added following lines

```
sudo vim /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp

file { '/etc/fuse.conf':
  ensure => present,
}->
file_line { 'Append a line to /etc/fuse.conf':
  path => '/etc/fuse.conf',
  line => 'Want to add this line as a test',
}
```

After that I ran this command

```
puppet apply /etc/puppet/modules/test/manifests/test.pp
```

Then I opened this file `/etc/fuse.conf` and there was no change in the file. The line was not added to the file. I don't understand what I am missing here. How can I do this? I am learning puppet. So this is only for learning purpose.

Comment: What version of Puppet? Is the stdlib module which provides file_line found in `$modulepath`? Do you have any errors in the console output of the `puppet apply` command?

Comment: The above example works for me.

Comment: Cross-posted: http://stackoverflow.com/q/36045455/781723, http://serverfault.com/q/764220/111679, http://superuser.com/q/1053789/93541.  Please [do not post the same question on multiple sites](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/64068). Each community should have an honest shot at answering without anybody's time being wasted.

Answer (score 1):

For `file_line` the Puppet Labs standard library has to be installed.

See https://puppet.com/blog/module-of-week-puppetlabs-stdlib-puppet-labs-standard-library for more information.

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
file { '/etc/fuse.conf':
  ensure => present,
}->
if "test `grep -q 'Want to add this line as a test' /etc/fuse.conf | wc -l` -eq 0" {
  exec { 'echo "Want to add this line as a test" >> /etc/fuse.conf':
       }
}
```

Comment: Does this work with Puppet 4 or something? I wasn't aware you could do bash style tests in an if statement. I tried it and it's a syntax error in Puppet 3, which is what I still use.

Comment: I'm looking at some of my old modules, so I'm not sure about the version. I know we were using the latest, so I would assume it's v4. If you comment out the if statement, does the exec command work?

Comment: No, you still need to tell Puppet where to find `echo`. You need a path attribute or fully qualify `/bin/echo`. Also, if you comment out the if, you'll get that line appended every time Puppet runs. OP's file_line is really the best way to do it. He just needs to troubleshoot why it isn't working.

Comment: This is not valid puppet code.

Answer (score -2):

You can try this:

`exec {'exec_name':
    command => 'bash -c "echo foo_bar" >> /path/to/file',
    path    => '/bin',
     }`

Tried most of the of the options and they all disappointed me.

Comment: This will append the line every puppet run.

Comment: @mzhaase - I've made an edit to resolve that issue